# Data directory in elastic search created inside project folder

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I am using Java API (maven project) for elastic search. I configured elasticsearch.yml for `path.data` field as one of the directories. But when I run my code for indexing, in addition to the folder mentioned in config yml file, it also creates a /data/ directory inside the root of the project folder. I am unable to understand why it do so. Can someone please help.

In elasticsearch.yml

> path.data: /data/servers/es.data

Thanks.

Comment: try to specify that it's an absolute path and not a relative path in your java application

Comment: relative or absolute paths? I am using Mac and this is the absolute path.. Also, when the additional /data/ directory is created in the project root folder, the path is /data/elasticsearch/nodes/...

Comment: First I said 'absolute path and not a relative path in your JAVA APPLICATION' and can you please update at least with output?

Comment: If you wish to understand how that works in a Java application, I suggest that your read about [Path Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) and [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) from the Javadoc

Comment: In elasticsearch.yml:- "path.data: /data/servers/es.data"   I created few index and this folder "/data/elasticsearch/nodes/...." is created in both the locations.  "/data/servers/es.data"  and  project root directory. Isn't this something to do with elasticsearch config properties.

Comment: You must be doing an override of the properties somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue. In my case (I use Spring Boot) I think the issue is, I forgot to define a bean of `org.elasticsearch.client.Client`. So I think Spring generated a Client bean and 'made' an elasticsearch DB in my project folder.

Hope this helps someone! Cheers